# rails carrierwave edit/update form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

In my rails project I use Carrierwave to upload images to S3 via fog. So far I have the Create Read and Delete portions of the CRUD spectrum working.

My problem is the edit/update portion. Im use the same `_form.html.erb` to edit that I used for creating records. When I click the edit link the form loads all of my data into the form fields for editing with the exception of the image.  The form field is blank as though there is no image associated with the record.

How do I update an image that is already saved to S3?

**Models/listing.rb**

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :price, :title, :image

  mount_uploader :image, ListingUploader
end
```

**Controllers/listings_controller.rb** (edit/update portion)

```
def edit
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    if @listing.update_attributes(params [:listing])
        redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @listing
    else
        render :action => 'edit'
    end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @listing, :html => { :multipart => true } do |l| %>
<p>
    <%= l.label :title %>
    <%= l.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= l.label :price %>
    <%= l.text_field :price %>
</p>

<p>
    <label>Upload a Picture</label>
    <%= l.file_field :image %>
    <%= l.hidden_field :image_cache %>
</p>
<div class="image-pre">
    <%= image_tag(@listing.image_url(:thumb)) if @listing.image? %>
</div>

<p>
    <%= l.label :body %>
    <%= l.text_area :body, :class => "tinymce" %>
    <%= tinymce %>
</p>

<%= l.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: U got any solution?? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your listings_controller.rb, try something like:

```
def edit
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    @listing.image.cache!
end
```

Haven't tested this out myself, but I think it might work, given that image_cache field is used to circumvent this problem normally.

Answer (score 0):

I had upgraded my app to Rails 6 sometime ago, then started experiencing this issue.

tldr; you need a carrierwave gem version 2.1.0 or higher for Rails 5.0 and up.

I used `bundle outdated --strict` to see if carrierwave could be upgraded. Check Gemfile to see if the requested version is set correctly. Also check Gemfile.lock to see if other gems are holding it back; you'll need to upgrade them as well. Then I used `bundle update --strict` to perform the actual upgrade.